# Clean way to add or remove options in multi-level dropdown menu according to security

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, binary-tree

I have a multi-level HTML5 dropdown menu like so:

```
TOP OPTION 1

   Option 1.1

      Option 1.1.1

      Option 1.1.2

   Option 1.2

      Option 1.2.1

      Option 1.2.2

TOP OPTION 2

   Option 2.1

      Option 2.1.1

      Option 2.1.2
```

(Only the leaf options are actionable, the rest work as groupers)

This menú is currently completely rendered in the application. Now I have to show the available options according to the permits the user has. The permits can apply over a whole grouper (like Option 1.1), in which case I have to show the grouper and all its children, or over only one of the leaf options (like Option 1.1.1), in which case I have to render the TOP OPTION 1 and Option 1.1 groupers and, in case that's the only child option the user has permits over, *only* the Option 1.1.1 item. So in this last case, the menu would look like:

```
TOP OPTION 1

   Option 1.1

      Option 1.1.1
```

It can also happen the user has no permits at all over any of the groupers or children, in which case you shouldn't render any children *nor* it's parent groupers.

The permits are got through a RESTful API and are basically just codes. If a user can access the whole TOP OPTION 1 tree, it will have a permit with a code like "topOptionOne_CRUD", with "CRUD" being the kind of operations over those functionalities it has permission to do (create, read, update, delete). It's supposed to be such that if I find this "topOptionOne_CRUD" permit, I won't find one that's called "topOptionOne.OptionOneOne_CRUD" (representing a permit over the Option 1.1 grouper) that would be redundant.

The menu is modeled as a JavaScript object, with the suboptions modeled as an Array of objects (there are some small differences in the kind of attributes top-level and leaf-level options have) which is later rendered in HTML with AngularJS:

```
{
                name: 'Header',
                enabled: enabledMenu.header,
                type: 'heading',
                children: [ {
                    name: 'OptionOne',
                    enabled: enabledMenu.optionOne,
                    type: 'toggle',
                    pages: [{
                        name: 'OptionOneOne',
                        enabled: enabledMenu.optionOneOne,
                        url: 'optionOneOne',
                        type: 'link'
                    },
                        {
                            name: 'OptionOneTwo',
                            enabled: enabledMenu.optionOneTwo,
                            url: 'optionOneTwo',
                            type: 'link'
                        }]
                }]
            }
```

I thought two possibilities to deal with this:

1. Add an enabled attribute in the menú tree model for each node, and have Angular render each node depending on whether it's enabled or not. That would mean searching among all the permit codes looking for each kind of permit and compose the values for top-level ones, because in case I don't have topOptionOne_CRUD, I could still have topOptionOne.OptionOneOne_CRUD, which would require TOP OPTION 1 to be rendered. I tried this approach and got a pretty ugly function with a lot of variables representing each permit for each option, and lots of .filter() operations to find each option's permits among the permits array.

It looks like this:

```
function loadEnabledMenuOptions(permits) {
            var allOptionOne= permits.filter(function (it) { return it.codigo.indexOf('topOptionOne_C') >= 0; }).length > 0;
            var optionOneOne= allOptionOne|| permits.filter(function (it) { return it.codigo.indexOf('topOptionOne.optionOneOne_C') >= 0; }).length > 0;
            var optionOneTwo= allOptionOne|| permits.filter(function (it) { return it.codigo.indexOf('topOptionOne.optionOneTwo_C') >= 0; }).length > 0;
            var optionOne= optionOneOne|| optionOneTwo;
            var header= optionOne;

            ...

            return {
                header: header,
                optionOne: optionOne,
                optionOneOne: optionOneOne,
                optionOneTwo: optionOneTwo,
                ...
            };
```

2. Build the object progressively, seeing each node to the full object only if the user has the permits for it,. I tried to decompose this in functions, like addTopOptionOne(menuObj, permits), which has other similar options inside to add its grouper suboptions, and modifying the menuObj passed by reference only if one of its suboptions has been added. This looks even messier in code than the first alternative

I wonder if there's some tree algorithm that could make this problem easier, or the code less messy. It just looks amateurish.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fairly broad question for SO. Might be a better fit over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Put the actual code please

Comment: @mccainz when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)